# Icomoon selection.json, add new icon for existing project

Tags: html, json, svg, fonts

I've try to add new icons to selection.json, I've downloaded the new json file, and see that icons where add. But they are not visible in index.html. I'm not seeing facebook and goole+ icons.The selection.json automaticaly updated my iconmoon.svf file. My selection.json code.
[image]

```js
{
  "IcoMoonType": "selection",
  "icons": [
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M325.8 457.4v111.8h184.8c-7.4 48-55.8 140.6-184.8 140.6-111.2 0-202-92.2-202-205.8s90.8-205.8 202-205.8c63.4 0 105.6 27 129.8 50.2l88.4-85.2c-56.8-53-130.4-85.2-218.2-85.2-180.2 0.2-325.8 145.8-325.8 326s145.6 325.8 325.8 325.8c188 0 312.8-132.2 312.8-318.4 0-21.4-2.4-37.8-5.2-54h-307.6z",
          "M1024 448h-96v-96h-96v96h-96v96h96v96h96v-96h96z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {"fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"}
        ],
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "tags": [
          "icon-google-plus"
        ],
        "grid": 16
      },
      "attrs": [
        {"fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"}

      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 68,
        "id": 2,
        "name": "google-plus",
        "prevSize": 32
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 0
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M608 192h160v-192h-160c-123.514 0-224 100.486-224 224v96h-128v192h128v512h192v-512h160l32-192h-192v-96c0-17.346 14.654-32 32-32z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {}
        ],
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "tags": [
          "icon-facebook"
        ],
        "grid": 16
      },
      "attrs": [
        {}
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 69,
        "id": 3,
        "name": "facebook",
        "prevSize": 32
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 1
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M1023.548 895.663h95.989l-925.257-804.571-95.989 110.388 925.257 804.571c27.521 23.932 68.468 23.932 95.989 0l925.257-804.571-95.989-110.388-925.257 804.571z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {
            "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
          }
        ],
        "width": 2048,
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "grid": 0,
        "tags": [
          "arrow-down"
        ],
        "colorPermutations": {
          "25520901255255255141637315378901": [
            {
              "f": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "attrs": [
        {
          "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 70,
        "id": 4,
        "name": "arrow-down",
        "prevSize": 32,
        "code": 59658
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 2
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M1119.538 91.092c-27.521-23.932-68.468-23.932-95.989 0l-925.257 804.571 95.989 110.388 925.257-804.571h-95.989l925.257 804.571 95.989-110.388-925.257-804.571z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {
            "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
          }
        ],
        "width": 2048,
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "grid": 0,
        "tags": [
          "arrow-up"
        ],
        "colorPermutations": {
          "25520901255255255141637315378901": [
            {
              "f": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "attrs": [
        {
          "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 71,
        "id": 5,
        "name": "arrow-up",
        "prevSize": 32,
        "code": 59659
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 3
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M3253.209 471.040h-3253.209v81.92h3264.334l-356.174 409.6 61.817 53.754 409.6-471.040c13.402-15.412 13.402-38.342 0-53.754l-409.6-471.040-61.817 53.754 345.049 396.806z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {
            "fill": "rgb(41, 63, 73)"
          }
        ],
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "grid": 0,
        "tags": [
          "icon-slim-right"
        ],
        "colorPermutations": {
          "25520901255255255141637315378901": [
            {
              "f": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        "width": 3400
      },
      "attrs": [
        {
          "fill": "rgb(41, 63, 73)"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 72,
        "id": 6,
        "name": "slim-right",
        "prevSize": 32,
        "code": 59660
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 4
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M944.73 147.119h-865.531c-43.372 0-79.199 35.827-79.199 79.199v571.363c0 43.37 35.827 79.199 79.199 79.199h865.531c43.37 0 79.199-35.827 79.199-79.199v-571.363c1.885-43.372-33.944-79.199-79.199-79.199zM648.678 533.686l329.995-254.568v511.021l-329.995-256.453zM81.084 194.261h863.644c15.085 0 28.285 11.315 32.057 24.515l-437.479 339.423c-16.972 13.2-45.257 13.2-60.342 0l-431.822-335.653c3.772-15.085 16.972-28.285 33.942-28.285zM47.142 790.139v-507.251l326.225 252.683-326.225 254.568zM81.084 833.509c-3.772 0-7.543 0-9.428-1.885l341.31-265.883 37.715 30.17c16.972 13.2 37.715 18.857 58.457 18.857s43.37-5.657 58.457-18.857l41.485-32.057 345.080 267.768c-3.772 1.885-5.657 1.885-9.428 1.885h-863.648z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {}
        ],
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "grid": 0,
        "tags": [
          "icon-envelope"
        ],
        "colorPermutations": {
          "25520901255255255141637315378901": [
            {}
          ]
        }
      },
      "attrs": [
        {}
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 73,
        "id": 7,
        "name": "envelope",
        "prevSize": 32,
        "code": 59661
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 5
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M279.175 938.846l-229.053-392.893c-98.627-170.307-47.427-392.354 116.413-491.52 54.434-33.954 119.107-54.434 184.32-54.434 126.114 0 245.76 64.674 307.2 181.086 61.44 108.867 64.674 238.754 0 348.16 0 0 0 0 0 6.467l-235.52 409.6c-17.246 20.48-44.733 37.726-71.68 37.726-27.486 0-54.973-17.246-71.68-44.194zM193.482 99.166c-136.354 81.92-180.547 272.707-92.16 416.067l229.053 399.36c6.467 17.246 16.707 17.246 20.48 17.246 3.234 0 16.707 0 20.48-17.246l235.52-402.594c0 0 0 0 0-7.006 54.434-92.16 54.434-208.034 0-300.194-47.966-92.16-147.133-150.366-256-150.366-54.973 0-109.406 17.246-157.373 44.733z",
          "M215.579 351.933c0-74.914 61.44-136.354 136.354-136.354 75.453 0 136.893 61.44 136.893 136.354 0 75.453-61.44 136.893-136.893 136.893-74.914 0-136.354-61.44-136.354-136.893zM270.013 351.933c0 44.733 37.726 81.92 81.92 81.92 44.733 0 81.92-37.187 81.92-81.92 0-44.194-37.187-81.92-81.92-81.92-44.194 0-81.92 37.726-81.92 81.92z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {
            "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
          },
          {
            "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
          }
        ],
        "width": 755,
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "grid": 0,
        "tags": [
          "icon-map-mark"
        ],
        "colorPermutations": {
          "25520901255255255141637315378901": [
            {
              "f": 3
            },
            {
              "f": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "attrs": [
        {
          "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
        },
        {
          "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 74,
        "id": 8,
        "name": "map-mark",
        "prevSize": 32,
        "code": 59648
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 6
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M610.743 978.651c-120.686-84.114-198.217-157.257-265.509-223.817-66.56-65.829-141.166-146.286-226.011-261.851-84.846-111.909-49.006-258.194 77.531-391.314 39.497-38.034 106.057-38.034 148.48 0l78.263 76.8c17.554 17.554 27.794 46.080 27.794 73.874s-10.24 55.589-27.794 73.143l-35.84 35.109c-10.24 10.24-6.583 27.794 0 38.034 39.497 49.006 106.057 122.149 148.48 157.257 38.766 38.766 106.057 104.594 159.451 147.017 10.24 10.24 27.794 10.24 38.766 0l35.109-35.109c38.766-38.766 106.057-38.766 148.48 0l77.531 76.8c18.286 17.554 28.526 45.349 28.526 73.143s-10.24 56.32-28.526 73.874c-73.874 87.040-158.72 132.389-243.566 132.389-49.737 0-102.4-17.554-141.166-45.349zM236.251 140.434c-113.371 111.909-134.583 230.4-74.606 317.44 84.846 119.223 152.137 188.709 219.429 258.926 67.291 66.56 141.166 132.389 261.12 216.503 92.16 62.903 208.457 38.034 321.829-73.143 10.24-10.971 10.24-21.211 10.24-35.109 0-10.971-6.583-21.211-10.24-35.109l-84.846-76.8c-17.554-17.554-49.737-17.554-67.291 0l-35.109 35.109c-28.526 27.794-74.606 27.794-113.371 0-56.32-38.766-123.611-111.909-162.377-150.674-38.766-38.034-113.371-111.177-152.137-160.183-27.794-38.766-27.794-84.114 0-111.909l35.84-35.109c10.24-10.24 10.24-20.48 10.24-35.109 0-13.897-7.314-20.48-10.24-34.377l-78.263-76.8c-10.24-7.314-24.869-13.897-35.109-13.897-10.971 0-21.211 6.583-35.109 10.24z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {
            "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
          }
        ],
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "grid": 0,
        "tags": [
          "icon-phone"
        ],
        "colorPermutations": {
          "25520901255255255141637315378901": [
            {
              "f": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "attrs": [
        {
          "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 75,
        "id": 9,
        "name": "phone",
        "prevSize": 32,
        "code": 59649
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 7
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M0 497.034c0-274.117 222.917-497.034 497.034-497.034 274.905 0 497.822 222.917 497.822 497.034 0 274.905-219.766 497.822-497.822 497.822-274.117 0-497.034-222.917-497.034-497.822zM58.289 497.034c0 241.822 197.711 439.532 438.745 439.532 241.822 0 439.532-197.711 439.532-439.532 0-241.034-197.711-438.745-439.532-438.745-241.034 0-438.745 197.711-438.745 438.745z",
          "M501.76 1015.335c-18.117 0-29.145-11.028-29.145-29.932v-877.489c0-18.117 11.028-29.145 29.145-29.145s29.145 11.028 29.145 29.145v881.428c0 14.966-11.028 25.994-29.145 25.994z",
          "M985.403 530.905h-877.489c-18.117 0-29.145-11.028-29.145-29.145s11.028-29.145 29.145-29.145h885.366c18.117 0 29.145 11.028 29.145 29.145s-18.117 29.145-37.022 29.145z",
          "M470.252 972.8c-135.483-47.262-233.945-244.972-233.945-486.006 0-245.76 98.462-446.622 233.945-486.794l88.222 18.117c0 18.117-11.028 29.145-29.932 29.145-127.606 0-233.945 197.711-233.945 439.532 0 241.034 106.338 438.745 233.945 438.745 18.905 0 29.932 11.028 29.932 29.145z",
          "M472.615 957.834c0-18.117 11.028-29.145 29.145-29.145 128.394 0 233.945-196.923 233.945-438.745 0-241.034-105.551-438.745-233.945-438.745-18.117 0-29.145-11.028-29.145-29.145l76.406-22.055c139.422 36.234 245.76 241.034 245.76 489.945 0 244.972-99.249 446.622-234.732 486.794z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {
            "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
          },
          {
            "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
          },
          {
            "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
          },
          {
            "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
          },
          {
            "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
          }
        ],
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "grid": 0,
        "tags": [
          "icon-globe"
        ],
        "colorPermutations": {
          "25520901255255255141637315378901": [
            {
              "f": 3
            },
            {
              "f": 3
            },
            {
              "f": 3
            },
            {
              "f": 3
            },
            {
              "f": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "attrs": [
        {
          "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
        },
        {
          "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
        },
        {
          "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
        },
        {
          "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
        },
        {
          "fill": "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 76,
        "id": 10,
        "name": "globe",
        "prevSize": 32,
        "code": 59650
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 8
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M544.64 279.040l370.56 196.48-370.56 195.2zM1304.32 72.96c-51.84-55.040-110.72-55.68-137.6-58.88-192-14.080-480-14.080-480-14.080h-0.64c0 0-288 0-480 14.080-26.88 3.2-85.76 3.84-137.6 58.88-41.6 42.24-55.040 138.24-55.040 138.24s-13.44 112.64-13.44 225.92v105.6c0 112.64 13.44 225.28 13.44 225.28s13.44 96 55.040 138.24c51.84 55.68 120.32 53.76 151.040 59.52 110.080 10.88 466.56 14.080 466.56 14.080s288.64-0.64 480.64-14.72c26.88-3.2 85.76-3.2 137.6-58.88 41.6-42.24 54.4-138.24 54.4-138.24s14.080-112.64 14.080-225.28v-105.6c0-113.28-14.080-225.92-14.080-225.92s-12.8-96-54.4-138.24z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {
            "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
          }
        ],
        "width": 1408,
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "grid": 0,
        "tags": [
          "icon-youtube"
        ],
        "colorPermutations": {
          "25520901255255255141637315378901": [
            {
              "f": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "attrs": [
        {
          "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 77,
        "id": 11,
        "name": "youtube",
        "prevSize": 32,
        "code": 59651
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 9
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M753.987 563.739c86.232 18.324 174.619 25.331 263.006 31.259 30.72 2.156 58.745-25.331 57.128-54.973 1.617-29.642-26.408-57.128-57.128-54.973-88.387 5.928-176.775 12.935-263.006 31.259-15.629 3.234-53.356 7.545-53.356 23.714s37.726 20.48 53.356 23.714z",
          "M50.661 53.895c-16.168 0.539-31.798 8.623-41.499 22.097-9.701 14.013-11.857 33.415-5.389 49.044 0 0 68.985 177.853 140.665 360.556 34.493 88.387 69.524 177.853 97.549 248.994-8.623 22.097-16.707 42.038-23.175 57.667-5.389 12.935-7.006 18.324-12.396 29.103-12.396 24.792-38.804 45.272-63.057 46.888-42.038 3.234-86.771 5.928-86.771 5.928-13.474 0.539-26.947 7.006-36.109 17.246-8.623 10.24-13.474 24.253-12.935 37.726 1.078 13.474 7.545 26.947 17.785 35.571 10.24 9.162 24.253 14.013 37.726 12.935 42.038-0.539 53.356 1.078 106.173-7.545 78.686-20.48 119.107-73.297 145.516-139.048 9.701-23.175 21.558-53.895 36.109-90.004 28.564-71.68 64.674-164.379 100.244-255.461 71.68-182.703 140.665-360.556 140.665-360.556 6.467-15.629 4.312-35.032-5.928-49.044-9.701-14.013-26.947-22.636-44.194-22.097-10.24 0.539-19.941 3.773-28.564 9.701-8.084 5.928-14.552 14.552-17.785 24.253 0 0-68.985 177.314-140.665 360.017-19.402 49.583-38.804 98.627-57.128 145.516-18.324-46.888-37.187-95.394-57.128-145.516-71.141-182.703-140.126-360.017-140.126-360.017-3.773-9.701-10.24-18.324-18.324-24.253s-17.785-9.162-28.025-9.701c-1.078 0-2.156 0-3.234 0z",
          "M681.768 700.093c64.135 60.362 136.354 112.101 208.573 162.762 25.331 17.785 63.596 9.162 77.608-17.246 16.707-24.792 6.467-62.518-21.019-76.531-78.147-40.421-157.373-80.303-240.909-109.406-15.091-5.389-49.583-21.558-57.667-7.545-8.623 14.013 21.558 37.187 33.415 47.966z",
          "M681.768 334.147c64.135-60.901 136.354-112.64 208.573-163.301 25.331-17.785 63.596-8.623 77.608 17.246 16.707 24.792 6.467 62.518-21.019 76.531-78.147 40.96-157.373 80.842-240.909 109.406-15.091 5.389-49.583 21.558-57.667 7.545-8.623-14.013 21.558-37.187 33.415-47.427z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {
            "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
          },
          {
            "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
          },
          {
            "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
          },
          {
            "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
          }
        ],
        "width": 1078,
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "grid": 0,
        "tags": [
          "icon-yammer"
        ],
        "colorPermutations": {
          "25520901255255255141637315378901": [
            {
              "f": 1
            },
            {
              "f": 1
            },
            {
              "f": 1
            },
            {
              "f": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "attrs": [
        {
          "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
        },
        {
          "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
        },
        {
          "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
        },
        {
          "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 78,
        "id": 12,
        "name": "yammer",
        "prevSize": 32,
        "code": 59652
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 10
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M1119.004 154.738c53.476-30.151 95.004-79.076 114.347-136.533-50.062 28.444-105.813 48.924-165.547 59.733-47.218-47.787-114.916-77.938-189.44-77.938-143.929 0-260.551 110.933-260.551 247.467 0 19.342 2.276 38.116 6.827 56.32-216.178-10.24-407.893-108.658-536.462-258.276-22.187 36.409-35.271 79.076-35.271 124.018 0 85.902 46.080 161.564 116.053 205.938-42.667-1.138-83.058-12.516-118.329-30.72v2.844c0 120.036 89.884 220.16 208.782 242.916-21.618 5.689-44.373 8.533-68.267 8.533-17.067 0-32.996-1.707-48.924-4.551 32.996 98.418 129.138 170.098 242.916 171.804-88.747 66.56-201.387 105.813-323.129 105.813-21.049 0-41.529-1.138-62.009-3.413 114.916 69.973 252.018 110.933 398.791 110.933 479.004 0 740.693-376.604 740.693-703.716 0-10.809-0.569-21.049-1.138-31.858 51.2-34.702 95.004-78.507 130.276-128-46.649 19.911-97.28 32.996-149.618 38.684z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {
            "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
          }
        ],
        "width": 1308,
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "grid": 0,
        "tags": [
          "icon-twitter"
        ],
        "colorPermutations": {
          "25520901255255255141637315378901": [
            {
              "f": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "attrs": [
        {
          "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 79,
        "id": 13,
        "name": "twitter",
        "prevSize": 32,
        "code": 59653
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 11
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M12.8 987.52h221.44v-666.24h-221.44zM248.96 115.2c-1.28-65.28-48-115.2-123.52-115.2-76.16 0-125.44 49.92-125.44 115.2 0 64 48 115.2 122.24 115.2h1.28c77.44 0 125.44-51.2 125.44-115.2zM776.96 305.92c145.28 0 254.72 94.72 254.72 299.52v382.080h-221.44v-356.48c0-89.6-31.36-151.040-112-151.040-60.8 0-97.28 41.6-113.28 81.28-5.76 14.080-7.68 33.92-7.68 53.76v372.48h-220.8c0 0 3.2-604.16 0-666.24h220.8v94.080c0 1.28-0.64 1.92-1.28 2.56h1.28v-2.56c30.080-45.44 82.56-109.44 199.68-109.44z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {
            "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
          }
        ],
        "width": 1088,
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "grid": 0,
        "tags": [
          "icon-linkedin"
        ],
        "colorPermutations": {
          "25520901255255255141637315378901": [
            {
              "f": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "attrs": [
        {
          "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 80,
        "id": 14,
        "name": "linkedin",
        "prevSize": 32,
        "code": 59654
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 12
    },
    
      
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M0 391.791c0-213.704 178.087-391.791 391.791-391.791s391.791 178.087 391.791 391.791c0 213.704-178.087 391.791-391.791 391.791s-391.791-178.087-391.791-391.791zM71.235 391.791c0 178.087 142.47 320.557 320.557 320.557s320.557-142.47 320.557-320.557c0-178.087-142.47-320.557-320.557-320.557s-320.557 142.47-320.557 320.557z",
          "M676.73 623.304l311.652 311.652c13.357 13.357 13.357 35.617 0 48.974-8.904 8.904-22.261 8.904-26.713 8.904-8.904 0-22.261 0-26.713-8.904l-311.652-311.652z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {
            "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
          },
          {
            "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
          }
        ],
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "grid": 0,
        "tags": [
          "icon-search"
        ],
        "colorPermutations": {
          "25520901255255255141637315378901": [
            {
              "f": 1
            },
            {
              "f": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "attrs": [
        {
          "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
        },
        {
          "fill": "rgb(53, 78, 90)"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 83,
        "id": 17,
        "name": "search",
        "prevSize": 32,
        "code": 59657
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 15
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M325.8 457.4v111.8h184.8c-7.4 48-55.8 140.6-184.8 140.6-111.2 0-202-92.2-202-205.8s90.8-205.8 202-205.8c63.4 0 105.6 27 129.8 50.2l88.4-85.2c-56.8-53-130.4-85.2-218.2-85.2-180.2 0.2-325.8 145.8-325.8 326s145.6 325.8 325.8 325.8c188 0 312.8-132.2 312.8-318.4 0-21.4-2.4-37.8-5.2-54h-307.6z",
          "M1024 448h-96v-96h-96v96h-96v96h96v96h96v-96h96z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {},
          {}
        ],
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "tags": [
          "google-plus"
        ],
        "grid": 16
      },
      "attrs": [
        {},
        {}
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 84,
        "id": 1,
        "name": "google-plus2, brand3, social3",
        "prevSize": 32
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 16
    },
    {
      "icon": {
        "paths": [
          "M608 192h160v-192h-160c-123.514 0-224 100.486-224 224v96h-128v192h128v512h192v-512h160l32-192h-192v-96c0-17.346 14.654-32 32-32z"
        ],
        "attrs": [
          {}
        ],
        "isMulticolor": false,
        "isMulticolor2": false,
        "tags": [
          "facebook",
          "brand",
          "social"
        ],
        "grid": 16
      },
      "attrs": [
        {}
      ],
      "properties": {
        "order": 85,
        "id": 0,
        "name": "facebook2, brand4, social4",
        "prevSize": 32
      },
      "setIdx": 0,
      "setId": 2,
      "iconIdx": 17
    }
  ],
  "height": 1024,
  "preferences": {
    "showGlyphs": true,
    "showCodes": true,
    "showQuickUse": true,
    "showQuickUse2": true,
    "showSVGs": true,
    "fontPref": {
      "prefix": "icon-",
      "metadata": {
        "fontFamily": "icomoon",
        "majorVersion": 1,
        "minorVersion": 0
      },
      "metrics": {
        "emSize": 1024,
        "baseline": 6.25,
        "whitespace": 50
      },
      "embed": false,
      "showSelector": false,
      "showMetrics": false,
      "showMetadata": false,
      "cssVars": true,
      "cssVarsFormat": "scss"
    },
    "imagePref": {
      "prefix": "icon-",
      "png": true,
      "useClassSelector": true,
      "color": 0,
      "bgColor": 16777215,
      "classSelector": ".icon"
    },
    "historySize": 100,
    "gridSize": 16
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
                            <li><span class="icon icon-facebook"></span><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
                            <li><span class="icon icon-instagram"></span><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                            <li><span class="icon icon-linkedin"></span><a href="#">Linked In</a></li>
                            <li><span class="icon icon-twitter"></span><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                            <li><span class="icon icon-yammer"></span><a href="#">Yammer</a></li>
                            <li><span class="icon icon-youtube"></span><a href="#">Youtube</a></li>
                            <li><span class="icon icon-google-plus"></span><a href="">Google+</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

Comment: I'll show you an easy way to use Icomoon fonts on your website and add the style you want. Use this link to for adding more icon to your website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998838/how-to-use-easily-icomoon-icon-to-website-change-colour-of-icon-and-adding-more/55999027#55999027

Answer (score 11):

So, how to add new icons to the icomoon set through selection.json:

1. Import the selection.json to icomoon app by clicking to "import icons".
2. Add the new icon your want to this set.
3. Then generate the font, and download zip file, extract it.
4. Copy all fonts from this archive to your dist/fonts, also copy the selection.json
5. Open the style.css from this archive and update your style.css or icon.scss(I use it). And update your task runner. All should work.